# How to allow only specific users to connect to a WebsocketConsumer in Django channels?

Tags: python, django, channel

I use django [channels](https://github.com/django/channels). I define a `JsonWebsocketConsumer`:

```
class Consumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    http_user = True

    def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
        if not message.user.is_superuser:
            self.disconnect(message, **kwargs)
```

But this doesn't work. Any user can connect and send data that `receive(self, text=None, bytes=None, **kwargs)` method will handle.

How can I allow only specific users to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used a wrong method.
There is `def close(self, status=True)` for `JsonWebsocketConsumer`.